# UITableViewCell separator insets don't work

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I set separator insets to 0 in my storyboard but  when I runs the code, the inset is not 0 . Is it the bug of iOS? Is it any workaround here? (I'm new in iOS development)

Comment: Please post the screenshot and are you checking in iOS device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `willDisplayCell` function of `UITableViewDelegate` to your code and set the `separatorInset` and `layoutMargins` of your cell:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
      cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero
      cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much